# Missing button to add storyboard in Visual Studio Blend

Tags: visual-studio, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, blend

In Blend, for some reason, I don't see the storyboard option PLUS sign button (#5) as described in this document link under section "Tour of the Objects and Timeline panel"

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj171012.aspx

Basically I have the whole row with 2 - 5 missing and as a result I see the objects & timeline tab and right below in 'Page'.

I found out this feature was remove in an update. Is there a work around to create animation like I could w/ the storyboard like this guy is doing starting at 3:20?

I attached my screen shot. [image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue. You could see it from Visual Studio Developer Community [Blend storyboards missing ("Objects and Timeline")](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/147968/blend-storyboards-missing-objects-and-timeline.html)

> As far as the missing storyboard UI is concerned, we do not support most Blend features like this in the new designer that you get when you target RS3 (10.0.16299).

So, as suggested by Marco Goertz, the workaround is you could temporarily retarget your app (lower to at least "Anniversary"), then the storyboards will show up again.